# How to read value from mysql database based on condition?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, swing, netbeans

I am doing a Java project to allow users to either log in as an admin or user based on what they selected from their account creation. I managed to do a code to check if their username and password were correct in my login page of the application by checking if those values are present in the database, however, I want the user to login as either an admin or user but I don't know how to do that. Im thinking if I can read what they selected as (either user or admin) from their account creation in the database (refer below for picture of database columns), then I am able to do an if statement based on that. For example if(usertype == 'admin'){ // then go to admin page} But usertype is a column in the database which I don't know how to read.I have my code below as well which is function that activates whenever the login button is pressed.If you know of a solution, let me know thank you.

```
private void LoginButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    Connection con;
    PreparedStatement pst;
    ResultSet rs;                                            
        try{
            String query = "SELECT * FROM `accounts` WHERE username=? and password=?"; // and usertype=?
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/restock", "root", "password");
            pst = con.prepareStatement(query);
            pst.setString(1, txtUsername.getText());
            pst.setString(2, txtPassword.getText());
            rs = pst.executeQuery();
            if(rs.next()){
                
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Login is successful as admin");
                mainpage admin = new mainpage();
                admin.setVisible(true);
                dispose();
            }
            else{
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Incorrect username or password");
                /*usermainpage user = new usermainpage();
                user.setVisible(true);
                dispose();*/
            }
            
        } catch(Exception ex){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, ex.getMessage());
        }
        
        
        
    }
```

This is a picture of the columns that are in my database
[image]

Comment: You know how to read from a database -- it's already in your code: `SELECT <criteria> FROM <table>`. You don't need to know how to select based on condition. You'll read `usertype` and store it as a variable in your application and use it as a condition *there*. What you actually need to do is to learn SQL. Google up a tutorial and get to reading because Stack Overflow isn't a place for learning fundamentals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're doing a SELECT *, you should be able to access the usertype in your java code with something like

```
if(rs.next()){
    String userType = rs.getString("usertype");
    if(userType.equals("admin")){
        // your admin code here
    }else{
        // your user code here
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I tried this code, but it seems like the else always runs. I tried loggin in with an admin account with correct details but it runs the else which is the user code. Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Debug your code and make sure you’re getting the data you’re expecting from your db

Comment: Please use equals method to compare two strings